# Xamarin Best Practice for Populating ListView and Page

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin Forms mobile app and plan to have a ListView of items which upon clicking one of the items links to another page with a ListView and then a page with text. I feel it would be much cleaner if the items for all pages  were stored in a database (SQLite.Net PCL) and then retrieved and used to generate the items in both ListView pages and text page. Is this a good way to do this or should I just be creating these lists by hardcoding the items in? Please keep in mind the lists are quite lengthy and the text page will have a lot of information that can be broken down into sections as well.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common way to create a ListView's datasource.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm new to how this works. Would the database have to be populated through the code or is there a way to create a table and populate it through the console or somewhere else?

Comment: you can create it through code, download it from a server, or create a pre-populated SQLite DB and add it to your project's bundle

Comment: imho using a data storage is a no brainer. a best practice would be to use the MVVM pattern instead of code behind to populate the listview and to navigate (and pass navigation parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a perfect way to do it!

Here is a sample Xamarin.Forms app that stores data in a SQLite Database and presents it in a ListView. Let me know if you have any questions about the code!

https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Brandon. I will check it out.